# Java Fair Queue

Tags: java, concurrency

I was looking at [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html)

For the `fair` option I can pass in the constructor, what does it actually mean to be fair?

> fair - if true then queue accesses for threads blocked on insertion or
>   removal, are processed in FIFO order; if false the access order is
>   unspecified.

From what I understand fair means FIFO? Not what I needed? Eg. 1 thread should not keep accessing the queue?

Comment: It means exactly what is described in the javadoc. What don't you understand? What's your question exactly?

Comment: @JBNizet, I was expecting fair to mean 1 thread should not be able to accessing the queue all the time (if there are other threads waiting). Isn't a normal queue dequeued in FIFO order?

Comment: That's the effect you'll have with the fair flag. If thread A gets an element from the queue, then thread B adds one, then thread C gets one, thread A will be served first, then B, then C. It doesn't have any relation to *which* element of the queue they will get. That depends on the type of the queue (Priority, Array, etc.) and on the method called. You're confusing the order of the elements in the queue, and the order in which threads can call methods on the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> FAIR is to implement a fair scheduling policyor to allow the
>   implementation to choose one. Fair scheduling sounds like the better
>   alternative, since it avoids the possibility that an unlucky thread
>   might be delayed indefinitely but, in practice, the benefits it
>   provides are rarely important enough to justify incurring the large
>   overhead that it imposes on a queue's operation. If fair scheduling is
>   not specified, ArrayBlockingQueue will normally approximate fair
>   operation, but with no guarantees.

[Reference with Code](http://codeidol.com/community/java/blockingqueue/13588/)

Comment: The reference link seems to have expired. Can you please update it?

Answer (score 2):

Fair means guaranteed FIFO access. Java 7 will literally create a queue for any thread that attempts to access the queue when it's lock has already been taken.

Fair queues will be significantly slower than unfair queues on a system with high usage of the Array Blocking Queue, due to the maintenance of the queue for thread ordering. If it isn't extremely important that all the threads progress at a very similar rate, it's probably worth keeping the queue unfair.

Comment: But shouldn't a normal queue be FIFO too? Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: normally, a queue isn't created to access the arrayblocking queue. Instead, the threads that are trying to access it continue trying to do so, over varying intervals of time. Whichever happens to be attempting to grab the arrayblockingqueue's lock earliest after it is freed gets it, rather than the thread that has been waiting the longest.

Comment: I think this last comment should have been the accepted answer -- it's clearest explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your problem, you can define what is fair. You can say that fair is a timeslot in wich a thread can access a resource. Or you can define fair as a thread accessing a resource in a first-in first-served manner.

FIFO is fair in the order of access to a resource.